# Positive/negative (semi) definite matrices

Tags: positive-definite

This is possibly a dumb question, but I'm trying to solve a linear system, say

```
Ax=b
```

A is a negative semi-definite matrix. I am using a math library, and want to use a method that only works for positive semi-definitive matrices. Could I simply just multiply -1 to both sides and then solve:

```
Dx=f
```

where

```
D=-A
f=-b
```

D now becomes positive semi definite.

Answer (score 0):

A matrix $A$ is negative semidefinite if and only if $x^T A x \leq 0$ for all $x$.  Then for any $x$, $x^T (-A) x = - x^T A x \geq 0$ so $-A$ is positive semidefinite.  Thus, your library for positive semidefinite matrices will work for solving the system $D x = f$.

Moreover, by multiplying both sides by $-1$, any solution to $A x = b$ is also a solution to $D x = f$.  Similarly, any solution to $D x = f$ is also a solution to $A x = b$ so they both have the same set of solutions.  Therefore, solving $D x = f$ is equivalent to solving $A x = b$.